# Need to capture expired token error issue refresh token request and send failed request back to laravel from angular

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5.5, angular-http-interceptors

I am using angular interceptor to add authorization token in the header. It works fine until the expiry of the token. The laravel sends a error of token_expired after the expiry of token. I need to capture that error in angular and send a request to issue a new token. After new token is issued i need to resend the failed request.

**Interceptor in angular code**

```
import {Injectable, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {LoginService} from './login.service';
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(public auth: LoginService) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${this.auth.getToken()}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: TokenInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
export class InterceptorModule { }
```

**Verify JWT middleware**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;


class VerifyJWTToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try{
            $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->bearerToken());
        }catch (TokenExpiredException $e){
            //JWTAuth::setToken(JWTAuth::refresh());
            return response()->json(['token_expired']);
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
                return response()->json(['error']);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Routes in laravel**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt.auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/symbol/count', 'SymbolController@count');

});
```

Is there any way i can capture all response from the server and check for token_expired error and reissue the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Catch `HttpErrorResponse` error:

```
  ...
    intercept(
                request: HttpRequest<any>,
                next: HttpHandler
            ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
                this.router = this.injector.get(Router);                   
                return next.handle(request).do(
                    (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        }
                    },
                    (err: any) => {
                        if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                            if (err.status === 401) {
                                // you can redirect to login page
                                this.router.navigate(['/login']);

                                // or do some request...
                            } else {
                                let title = 'Server error';
                                ...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
```

> It would be right if the user is idle for x number of minutes. But if
>   he is continuously online then why he has to re authorised

Add token renewal functionality to your `auth.service`, which called after some period of time. Good example written [here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/05-token-renewal)

Comment: I can capture error from this method but how i can issue refresh token request and send the request again which failed because of expiry

Comment: @Abhishek, logically user need to re-authorize to the system

Comment: It would be right if the user is idle for x number of minutes. But if he is continuously online then why he has to re authorised.